# howto make subclassing with value parameters compatible with mypy generics?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I'm looking for an easy way to pass a parameter to a subclass. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/ provides such a notation: `class C(Base, arg=value)`. This works perfecly and typechecks correctly via mypy for a normal class, but it fails with a generic class inheriting some Generic[T] (see code below). What did I miss ?

I'm using Python 3.6.8 (stock Python3 of Ubuntu 18.04) and mypy 0.740.

Here are two minimal standalone examples: one can put them in two .py files, typecheck them and run them.

this code typechecks and runs fine:

```py
# ok.py
# PEP 487, adapted from QuestBase example

class Foo(object):
    variable = "???"
    def __init_subclass__(cls, arg: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        cls.variable = arg
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs) # type: ignore

class Bar(Foo, arg="value"): ...

print(Bar.variable)
```

This code typechecks but fails at runtime with `TypeError: __init_subclass__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'`:

```py
# problem.py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T')

# PEP 487, adapted from QuestBase example

class Foo(Generic[T]):
    variable = "???"
    def __init_subclass__(cls, arg: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        cls.variable = arg
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs) # type: ignore

class Bar(Foo[T], arg="value"): ... # crash
```

Crash log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "problem.py", line 12, in <module>
    class Bar(Foo[T], arg="value"): ... # crash
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 682, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 1143, in __getitem__
    orig_bases=self.__orig_bases__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 978, in __new__
    self = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, _root=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 137, in __new__
    return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py", line 133, in __new__
    cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init_subclass__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'
```

Obviously the crash in Python internal files reveals a problem in my file. Again, what did I miss ?

Is there a *really typechecked* solution or workaround ?

The following example is not a nice solution (wrong but typechecks):

```py
# fake.py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T')


class Foo(Generic[T]):
    variable = "???"

class Bar(Foo[T]):
    variable = "value"

class KO(Foo[T]):
    ... # forgot assignment but still typechecks


print(KO.variable) # "???"
```

The following example, using a function which builds a class, is fine at runtime but doesn't typecheck: mypy doesn't recognize the result of a function as a derivable base class:

```py
# param.py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Type
T = TypeVar('T')

class Foo(Generic[T]):
    variable = "???"

def bar(arg: str) -> Type[Foo[T]]:
    class C(Foo[T]):
        variable = arg
    return C

Bar: Type[Foo[float]] = bar("value")
print(Bar.variable)

class Baz(Bar): ... # doesn't typecheck
print(Baz.variable)
```

Error log:

```
param.py:16: error: Variable "param.Bar" is not valid as a type
param.py:16: error: Invalid base class "Bar"
```

Comment: Are you sure you called it `arg` and not `args` or something? (Both would fail, if I'm reading the code correctly, but the error message seems wrong for `arg`.)

Comment: (Check all places you used this argument name, including without limitation the definition of `__init_subclass__` and the point where you tried to create `Bar`.)

Comment: There is no other place where the argument is used. The snippets are standalone minimal examples. I just edited the post to make it clear.

Comment: Ah, there's another error happening before the error I was expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your Python version, `Foo[T]` may be a subclass of `Foo`, or it may be some other weird object. Python 3.6.8 is one of the versions where `Foo[T]` is a subclass of `Foo`. Since it's a subclass of `Foo`, it needs to be created with some value of `arg`, but it doesn't have one, hence the error.

On Python 3.7 and 3.8, `Foo[T]` is not a subclass of `Foo`, and in fact, it isn't a class at all. On those versions, your code should work fine. (I tested 3.7.0, and it worked.) I wouldn't count on it staying fine, though. They keep making weird new changes to the `typing` internals, so stuff might break in the future.

Comment: Not the deep technical solution I hoped, but common sense one. I whish I could use standard Ubuntu 18.04 Python but fighting with flaws of old versions is not worth the effort. Thank you for your help. I mark your answer as accepted.